# nexus admin rights for particular repository

Tags: maven, nexus

This is a follow-up to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20262676/nexus-access-rights-for-particular-repository) question.  I would like to give a user Nexus administration rights to a particular repository, e.g., the ability to change its redeployment policy.  Privileges seem to concern only CRUD.  Is there a way to do this?  Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I put in a ticket to Nexus support.  It turns out that Nexus does not allow configuration privileges to be restricted by repository.  I ended up creating a user that had only configuration privileges, e.g., could not create new users but could change redeployment policy, and I'll just have to trust that user not to go outside the specified repository.